# Configure PIC18f2455 to use RS232

Tags: pic, usart

I'm using USART of PIC18f2455 with RS232 and having some trouble to configure it.

I'm using a 24 MHz Crystal Oscillator. 
The PLL is enabled with prescaler of 6 (to set 4MHz at input) and gives a fixed 96 MHz at output. 
The postscaler is set to 6 giving at end a 16MHz to Microcontroller clock.

With this clock I set the SPBRG of OpenUSART function to 25 for a Baud Rate of 9600 .

This is my USART config:

`#pragma config PLLDIV = 6, CPUDIV = OSC4_PLL6, USBDIV = 2, FOSC = HSPLL_HS
OpenUSART(USART_TX_INT_ON & USART_RX_INT_OFF & USART_ASYNCH_MODE & USART_EIGHT_BIT & USART_CONT_RX & USART_BRGH_LOW, 25);`

It is getting stuck at OpenUSART function...

Comment: Can you include this OpenUSART fucntion code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 16MHz microcontroller clock change `USART_BRGH_LOW, 25` to `USART_BRGH_HIGH, 103` which will result in [9,615.38 baud (9600 -0.2%)](http://www.piclist.com/techref/microchip/spbrgcalc.asp). Why not use `CPUDIV = OSC1_PLL2` to give you a 48 MHz clock? You'd then use `USART_BRGH_LOW, 77`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, your configuration worked after I solved others Interruption problems..